# Where is the jumper to reset BIOS on Toshiba Satellite e45w-c4200x

Tags: bios, passwords, reset, cmos

i am from Indonesia, please helpme...
show to me where key position to reset bios password... on thosiba satellite e45w-c4200x

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please make better photos with higher resolution and put in your query (use the "edit" option). Search for PCB jumper with the label "JRST", "CLRTC" or "JCMOS". It must be there somewhere. Do not forget to disconnect the CMOS battery before shorting the found jumper ! It may help to reset the BIOS even if you disconnect the CMOS battery for 1 min. and attach it back.

Comment: Thx Sirr... My device have done to use

Comment: Please at least write how you did it. Also for other people who will look for the same problem on the internet :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Second picture: bottom middle (between fan & battery) is a coin cell battery (red/black wire) you can unplug from your motherboard for a bit while battery & power cord disconnected. Maybe even turn it on when it's disconnected. You may even have to short the connector with a paperclip or something, but be very careful not to touch anything else besides the pins inside that connector/jack

Comment: @HerlanK4RDU5 - Edit your question instead of using comments

Comment: [1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S7mM.jpg "pic"

Comment: That is the back side of the connector, you'd pull the white plug & wires from the opposite side